# Move xaxis origin left towards the yaxis crossing

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

When moving the [yspine position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244380/pyplot-move-origin-with-axis) to the x-origin, other chart addons like hlines do stick out. The other way: Moving the xorigin to towards the yaxis, but how?

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1)
axs = [axs]
axs[0].plot(np.arange(10))
axs[0].axhline(y=2, lw=0.6, ls='-', color='k', xmin=0)
axs[0].spines['left'].set_position('zero')
```

Example of moving the spine which makes other stuff stick out, which would be lots of adjust on fancy chart. Upper picture untouched, below with spine zero positioned:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to set the limits of the x axis to start at 0:

```
axs[0].set_xlim(0)
```

Comment: is it possible to use rcParam for this? its not in `plt.rcParams.keys() `

Comment: I doubt it's a parameter there. That's more for styling.